# Casting checksum256 type to uint64_t type

Tags: eosiocpp

I have a `checksum256` type, I want to reach its specific elements as an integer.
Ex

```
cheksum256 myvar = 3dd6a4a0c86763d2a6fc1d5544eb58f3953b7cd03882e700b420fa0a89129f66;
```

I want `myvar[0]` and `myvar[2]` as an `int` type.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if i get the question right, probably something like this is what you looking for.

```
auto checksumBytes = myvar.extract_as_byte_array().data();
uint64_t num1, num2;
memcpy(&num1, &checksumBytes[0], sizeof(num1));
memcpy(&num2, &checksumBytes[7], sizeof(num2));
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer but I get this error:      
error: array initializer must be an initializer list or string literal
        unsigned char checksumBytes[32] = myvar.extract_as_byte_array().data();

Comment: sry, use auto "checksumBytes" instead of "unsigned char checksumBytes[32]"

Comment: Thank you very much